# Como inserir dados em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, sql-insert

Preciso fazer uma inserção da seguinte forma:

Tenho duas tabelas `TABELA 1` e `TABELA 2` e um Formulário de cadatro.
Este formulário possui tres inputs: `input 1, input 2, input 3`
O `input 1` deve ser inserido na `TABELA 1`.
O `input 2 e input 3` precisam ser inseridos na `TABELA 2`
Porem a `TABELA 2` possui um campo de chave estrangeira da `TABELA 1` que é a chave estrangeira do `input 1`.
Preciso fazer com que ao efetuar o `submit` do formulário os campos sejam gravados nas tabelas e o campo de chave estrangeira da `TABELA 2` receba o ID da nova inserção que foi feita na `TABELA 1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `mysql_insert_id` para o `MySQL` ou a função `mysqli_insert_id` para o `MySQLi`

[Fonte MySQL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php)
[Fonte MySQLi](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp)

Por exemplo:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES ('test')";
mysql_query( $query1 );

$id = mysql_insert_id();

$query2 = "INSERT INTO test_2 (test_id, value) VALUES ({$id}, 'test')";
mysql_query( $query2 );
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago testarei e assim que testar volto para marcar sua resposta :) Obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: Não sei o que aconteceu mas a segunda Query não executa, a primeira query executa normalmente e o nome é gravado corretamente no banco de dados em sua tabela, porem os dados do segundo INSERT não são gravados.

Comment: Faz o seguinte, comenta a linha `mysql_query( $query2 );` e dá um `echo` na variável `$query2`, depois posta aqui o resultado.

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações no código e funcionou perfeitamente o erro estava no meu código Muito obrigado Thiago!

Comment: Muito bom, consegui resolver meu problema graças a sua dica.
Abraço.